# Django 1.10 / Apache 2.4.18, Internal Server Error "No module named urls"

Tags: python, django, apache

(Ubuntu 16.04, Django 1.10, Apache 2.4.18, mod_wsgi, no virtualenv.) I finished my app (I'm NOT following the tutorial ;)), testing it using the light Django development server -- no errors there. Before deployment I want to test it 'at home' using an apache server on my laptop. I moved the project, called 'zarzif', to /var/www/html, so that manage.py is in /var/www/html/zarzif (and 'import zarzif' is working in that location). The file wsgi.py is in /var/www/html/zarzif/zarzif. My apache2.conf contains the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/zarzif/zarzif/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/zarzif/

<Directory /var/www/html/zarzif/zarzif>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

However, starting the server and going to 127.0.0.1 results in "500 Internal Server Error" and the error.log says (in a few copies)

```
from django.urls import reverse, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
ImportError: No module named urls, referer: http://127.0.0.1/
```

What am I doing wrong? I checked a few related questions, but I found none with this particular issue. Thanks in advance!

(Not sure if this is important, but the group www-data owns both /var/www/html and /var/www/html/zarzif.)

EDIT: @David542's solution below is to import `reverse` from `django.core.urlresolvers` instead. I have no idea why, since I'm using Django 1.10, but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has been deprecated since version 1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#module-django.urls.

> "In older versions, these functions are located in django.core.urlresolvers".

Here's what I'm doing to import `reverse` using a version prior to 1.10+

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 13, 'final', 0)
>>> from django.urls import reverse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urls
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't think that's it. I'm using Django 1.10 and the command `from django.urls import reverse` results in no error!

Comment: @LeszekWroński ok, so replace `from django.urls` with `from django.core.urlresolvers` in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, a similar error message remains (and isn't `django.urls` the correct location of `reverse` in 1.10?). I edited the original post to contain more of the traceback. Could the issue be that I have an app in the project I should do something with?

Comment: @LeszekWroński No -- you did `from django.urlresolvers`. That is not the correct path. It should be `from django.core.urlresolvers`.

Comment: Apologies. Yes, it now works. Could you give me some suggestion why? What you wrote seems to indicate that importing `reverse` from `django.core.urlresolvers' is now deprecated, and in the version of Django I'm using I should import from `django.urls`. I have no idea why your solution works and I would like to understand it...

Comment: @LeszekWroński for this you'd need to inspect the django package that you've installed. Why don't you open up the django folder and then just navigate through the directories. I'm guessing in the version you have there is not a folder called "urls" in the root folder but there is one called "core". Check it out!